# Is it correct to say "This train not taking passengers"?

Tags: grammaticality

I hear this announcement often at the train-station. Is this grammatically correct, without an 'is' after the word 'train'?

Comment: I'm guessing it's similar to other announcement-style messages like "Door locked" or "Prices reduced".

Comment: This space intentionally left blank.

Comment: I can understand the point of ellipsis in the case of a sign/poster (e.g. to save space on the board), but what would someone lose if they uttered an extra 'is'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fine for train-station announcements and the like. A form of ellipsis. Means dropping some syntax. Got it?

> **ellipsis** |iˈlipsis|
>   *noun* ( pl. -ses |-sēz|)
>   the omission from speech or writing of a word or words that are superfluous or able to be understood from contextual [NOAD]

Just don't use this particular form of ellipsis in formal writing and you should be fine.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds to me like the station announcer doesn't have a very good command of English.

Comment: @Fumble: Really? Were you confused by the announcement, or by  any part of my response?

Comment: @Robusto: I mean by my standards of acceptable English, that is one ellipsis too far. If I employed train-station announcers I would not have hired the one at OP's station.

Comment: @Fumble: Not everyone needs to talk like an English professor 100% of the time.

Comment: I would accept this as a sign on the side of the train, like a longer version of the "Not In Service" signs I see on buses here in Los Angeles.  But I agree with @Fumble that fragments and hyper-ellipses like this are quite jarring when spoken.

Comment: I'd go further-- I think this particular example would be rare even in a spoken announcement, but as you say would be quite normal on a written notice.

Comment: @Robusto: I think @Neil Coffey and @MT_Head have put their (collective) finger on what I couldn't pin down myself before. If it were a notice *on the side of the train itself* I'd accept the missing words without really noticing. As a spoken announcement I think it is *never* 'acceptable'. Though I've no doubt it occurs often enough here in the UK - we have a lot of people from the Indian subcontinent, and if I'm not much mistaken they're particularly prone to this type of error because of the way English syntax maps to their native languages.

Comment: @Fumble: I listened on the train this morning. At all stops the automatic announcement said "Now approaching ... [station name]." No copula. In journalism, this is called a "telegraphic style" and is used in headlines: "Two killed in crash" I see that this style irritates you, but it doesn't bother me at all.

Comment: @Robusto: I don't think it's a question of being 'irritated'. I don't mind the usage at all in headlines, or written notices on trains. I'm simply saying I think it would be *extremely* rare for a competent speaker to use it *in an announcement* deliberately. So much so that I would say almost every such usage would be down to the speaker *not* being a competent speaker. And I would bet almost any money that the percentage of 'originally native Indian' speakers working in UK train stations is higher than the percentage of the population as a whole.

Comment: @Fumble: This is where you and I differ. I would not say that such a person is not a competent speaker. He is competent for the level of English he uses every day. It may fluster you, but that's life. Not everyone will meet your high standards of communication.

Comment: @Robusto: If we differ, it's probably in our definition of *competent speaker*. You seem to imply that means *able to communicate sufficiently well to be understood*, whereas for me it means *fully conversant with the grammar of the language in question*. I don't think it's a formal linguistic term, but I'm accustomed to using it in that way. And to repeat - it doesn't fluster me at all. I live in a town with a very high Asian immigrant population; I don't think I'm prejudiced against them, but I do notice these types of errors simply because the 'natives' don't make them.